# Moving data from sqs to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have a queue in SQS that many notifications with data are pushed into it (more than 9M notifications a day)

I'd like to know if there is a way to create s3 objects from messages in sqs to s3 (path is being mentioned in attribute of the meesage)

I prefer to have an out-of-the-box solution without coding. 
If such a solution doesn't exist, would you recommend to have a lambda function to do that instead of a process (code runs on ec2)

Thanks,

Comment: _WHY_ are you wanting to do this? What is your actual use-case? Are you wanting a backup of the data? What will you be doing with the objects in Amazon S3? Do you _really_ want to create 9 million objects per day in an S3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

I found an [official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html) describing something similar to what you want to achieve -- it's more recommended in case you have big/large messages. As of today, feature is only available in the Java SDK. Example:

```
/*
 * Set the Amazon SQS extended client configuration with large payload
 * support enabled.
 */
final ExtendedClientConfiguration extendedClientConfig =
            new ExtendedClientConfiguration()
                    .withLargePayloadSupportEnabled(s3, S3_BUCKET_NAME);

final AmazonSQS sqsExtended =
            new AmazonSQSExtendedClient(AmazonSQSClientBuilder
                    .defaultClient(), extendedClientConfig);
```

Example reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/working-java-example-using-s3-for-large-sqs-messages.html

Comment: This is providing a method of handling "large messages" by storing the large information in Amazon S3, then merely providing a _reference_ to the data within the SQS message. I think the OP is asking how to _export_ the content of a message to S3, to a path given in an attribute of the message.

Comment: Thanks John, it makes sense. Edited the answer as "describing something similar to what you want to achieve". Let's see if he answers back with the use-case.